# Proportionally sized symbols in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot to plot proportional area symbols seems to require using `sqrt()` to achieve true proportionality:

```
require(ggplot2)

t <- data.frame(x=rep(c(1:5),5), y=rep(c(1:5),each=5), s=round(seq(1,100,length.out=25)))
t
p <- ggplot(data=t, aes(x=x,y=y))

# direct size-to-variable mapping
p + geom_point(aes(size=s), pch=22, fill='#0000FF75', col=NA) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 40)) +
  geom_text(data=t, aes(x=x,y=y,label=s),size=3,vjust=1)

# proportional area size-to-variable mapping
p + geom_point(aes(size=sqrt(s)), pch=22, fill='#0000FF75', col=NA) +
  scale_size(range = c(1, 40)) +
  geom_text(data=t, aes(x=x,y=y,label=s),size=3,vjust=1)
```

[image]

As you can see the labels are rooted when I need them to show the original data.  Have tried playing with the scale_size options but nothing works.  Anyone know a fix to this, or 
is there maybe an obscure setting to achieve proportional area size mapping?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `scale_area` instead of `scale_size`:

```
p + geom_point(aes(size=s), pch=22, fill='#0000FF75', col=NA) +
  scale_area(range = c(1, 40)) +
  geom_text(data=t, aes(x=x,y=y,label=s),size=3,vjust=1)
```

[image]

---

I agree, it's not entirely obvious, but not that obsure either - there is an example using `scale_area` in the help for `?scale_size`.

Comment: Thanks @Andrie that's solved it. I've edited the title of this question to reflect the solution.